# Variance of a polynomial series from a uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I intend to derive the variance of $Z$: 
$$Z \equiv \alpha_0+\alpha_1X+\alpha_2X^2+\dots + \alpha_MX^M = \sum_{m=0}^{M}\alpha_mX^m $$ for some $0 < M < \infty$ where each $\alpha_m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X \in [0,1]$ is a standardized random uniform variable.

For $M=2 \mbox{, } Z= \alpha_0+\alpha_1X+\alpha_2X^2$. Therefore, using the relation: 
$$ \text{Var}(\alpha_1X+\alpha_2Y) =\alpha_1^2\text{Var}(X) +\alpha_2^2\text{Var}(Y) + 2\alpha_1\alpha_2\text{Cov}(X, Y)$$ I found :
$$\text{Var(Z)} = \frac{\alpha_1^2}{12}+\frac{4 \alpha_2^2}{45} + \frac{2 \alpha_1\alpha_1}{12}$$

So, I am demanding help in deriving the variance for any $M$ or at least for $M=3,4,5 \text{ and } 6$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that
$$
\operatorname{Var}\bigg(\sum_{m=1}^Ma_mX^m\biggr)
=\sum_{m=1}^Ma_m^2\operatorname{Var}X^m+2\sum_{l=1}^{M-1}\sum_{m=l+1}^Ma_la_m\operatorname{Cov}(X^l,X^m).
$$

We need to calculate
$$
\operatorname{Var}X^m=\operatorname EX^{2m}-(\operatorname EX^m)^2
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X^l,X^m)=\operatorname EX^{l+m}-\operatorname EX^l\operatorname EX^m.
$$

If $X\sim U(0,1)$, then
$$
\operatorname E X^n=\int_0^1x^n\mathrm dx=\frac{1}{n+1}.
$$

I hope this helps.